# QPushButton can not be disabled when using setEnabled()

Tags: python, pyside6

I defined QPushButton in init function of a class, like this,

```
    self.datashowbtn = QPushButton("View")
    self.datashowbtn.clicked.connect(self.DrawQualCurve)
```

and to avoid user trigger button during dealing with data, I disable button in the following way,

```
    def DrawQualCurve(self):    
        print("DrawCurve")
        self.datashowbtn.setEnabled(False)
        #deal with data and draw curve here
```

However, when I run the code, user still can push 'datashowbtn' while DrawQualCurve is ongoing.
not sure if any other status or parameters need to set?

###as guys suggested, here I create a demo for debugging,

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import QThread,Signal

class Mythread(QThread):
    finishParse = Signal(bool)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mythread, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        #data routine
        self.finishParse.emit(False)
        for index in range(20):
            print("do something here!")
            self.msleep(300)
        self.finishParse.emit(True)    
        self.exit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        self.datashowbtn = QPushButton("View")
        self.demothread = Mythread()
        self.datashowbtn.clicked.connect(self.DrawQualCurve)
        self.datashowbtn.setCheckable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.datashowbtn)
        

    def DrawQualCurve(self):
        print("DrawCurve")
        self.datashowbtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.demothread.finishParse.connect(self.ParseDone)
        self.demothread.start()
    def ParseDone(self):
        print("ParseDone")
        self.datashowbtn.setEnabled(True)
        
        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

It seems that

1. setEnabled(true) works well before I start a thread in 'DrawQualCurve',
2. and if I increase more job in thread, this issue (or may not be) will more easily be reproduced. e.g. change self.msleep(300) to self.msleep(10), this issue will hardly reproduced.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante, add demo as you suggested, and it seems something related with thread. That is, when I start a thread connect to pushbutton, with heavy computational cost, setEnabled(False) will be ineffective.

Comment: You're emitting `finishParse` at the beginning of `run()`, meaning that `ParseDone` is called immediately after the thread is started. I'm not sure what would be the meaning of that bool argument, but you could add it to the function (`def ParseDone(self, state):`) and eventually call `setEnabled(state)`. Note that calling `exit()` only has sense when the thread is running its event loop, but since you're overriding `run()` there is no event loop, so calling `exit()` is useless.

Comment: @musicamante, yes, you are right! This is indeed caused by ```self.finishParse.emit(False)```, that I intended to do something like initialization, in ```run()```. But slot function will be called whatever the emit value of connected signal is. So, button is enabled immediately when thread is started. Thanks.